# Sentence Structure - “You've got vs you got to see

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I would like to check if my following sentence structure is correct.

> You've got to see my enemy's face when I was winning.

or

> You got to see my enemy's face when I was winning.

Comment: Do you mean "enemy" or "opponent"?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to say, you're using the incorrect modal. Recommendation = should. Example: "You should've seen my opponent's face when I won."

Answer (score 1):

The OP's sentence: You got to see my enemy's face when I was winning.

Grammatical: Yes but the **have got form** here specifically would be incorrect for this specific meaning.

Specific idiomatic usage of to **get to do something**: 
* I got to go to the sports' event last night [because I had tickets].

* He didn't get to see the movie on TV because he arrived late.

* He got to see  his favorite band at the concert last  night.

Meaning: to be able to do something when there is something else that could have stopped you from doing it or interfered with your doing it.

Compare the above to: to have to/have got to:

You just have to see that movie. It's great.
You've just got to see that movie. It's great.

Caveat; The story of get in English is very complicated. I am only addressing the specific idiomatic usage of to get to do something as possibly confused with to have/have got to do something (meaning: must do something).

**The present perfect of get to do something** in AmE is: have gotten to do something.

**I have not gotten to go out at night recently**. [meaning: not been able to]

The present perfect of get to do something in BrE would be: to **have got to do something** because the Brits do not use gotten anymore.

That said, this idiom is more likely to be expressed in BrE as: to manage to do something. Manage to do something is also  used in AmE.